# How to define a class that allows uniform access to different records in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have two records that both have a field I want to extract for display. How do I arrange things so they can be manipulated with the same functions? Since they have different fields (in this case `firstName` and `buildingName`) that are their name fields, they each need some "adapter" code to map `firstName` to `name`. Here is what I have so far:

```
class Nameable a where
  name :: a -> String

data Human = Human {
  firstName :: String
}

data Building = Building {
  buildingName :: String
}

instance Nameable Human where
  name x = firstName x

instance Nameable Building where
  -- I think the x is redundant here, i.e the following should work:
  -- name = buildingName
  name x = buildingName x

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStr $ show (map name items)
  where
    items :: (Nameable a) => [a]
    items = [ Human{firstName = "Don"}
            -- Ideally I want the next line in the array too, but that gives an 
            -- obvious type error at the moment.
            --, Building{buildingName = "Empire State"}
            ]
```

This does not compile:

```
TypeTest.hs:23:14:
    Couldn't match expected type `a' against inferred type `Human'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for `items' at TypeTest.hs:22:23
    In the expression: Human {firstName = "Don"}
    In the expression: [Human {firstName = "Don"}]
    In the definition of `items': items = [Human {firstName = "Don"}]
```

I would have expected the `instance Nameable Human` section would make this work. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong, and for bonus points what "concept" I am trying to get working, since I'm having trouble knowing what to search for.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897306/haskell-record-syntax-and-type-classes) feels similar, but I couldn't figure out the connection with my problem.

Comment: If you remove the type-annotation for `items` then it works... However, items has type `[Human]` (which is perhaps not what you want?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider the type of `items`:

```
items :: (Nameable a) => [a]
```

It's saying that for any `Nameable` type, `items` will give me a list of that type. It does *not* say that `items` is a list that may contain different `Nameable` types, as you might think. You want something like `items :: [exists a. Nameable a => a]`, except that you'll need to introduce a wrapper type and use `forall` instead. (See: [Existential type](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Existential_type))

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-} 

data SomeNameable = forall a. Nameable a => SomeNameable a 

[...]

items :: [SomeNameable]
items = [ SomeNameable $ Human {firstName = "Don"},
          SomeNameable $ Building {buildingName = "Empire State"} ]
```

The quantifier in the data constructor of `SomeNameable` basically allows it to forget everything about exactly which `a` is used, except that it is `Nameable`. Therefore, you will only be allowed to use functions from the `Nameable` class on the elements.

To make this nicer to use, you can make an instance for the wrapper:

```
instance Nameable (SomeNameable a) where
    name (SomeNameable x) = name x
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
Main> map name items
["Don", "Empire State"]
```

Comment: I wish GHC didn't have existential quantification.  It confuses more than it helps.  Question: what is the difference between `SomeNameable` and `String`?

Comment: @luqui: in this case, since `name` is the only operation available you may as well apply it straight away! You're only ever going to get `String`s out of a list of `SomeNameable`. Introduce modifying combinators like `changeName :: String -> a -> a` to `Nameable` and things get interesting!

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. Now I need to figure out if it's appropriate for my actual problem or I can get away with a union type.

Answer (score 8):

Everybody is reaching for either existential quantification or algebraic data types.  But these are both overkill (well depending on your needs, ADTs might not be).

The first thing to note is that *Haskell has no downcasting*.  That is, if you use the following existential:

```
data SomeNameable = forall a. Nameable a => SomeNameable a
```

then when you create an object

```
foo :: SomeNameable
foo = SomeNameable $ Human { firstName = "John" }
```

the information about which concrete type the object was made with (here `Human`) is forever lost.  The only things we know are: it is some type `a`, and there is a `Nameable a` instance.

What is it possible to do with such a pair?  Well, you can get the `name` of the `a` you have, and... that's it.  That's all there is to it.  In fact, there is an isomorphism.  I will make a new data type so you can see how this isomorphism arises in cases when all your concrete objects have more structure than the class.

```
data ProtoNameable = ProtoNameable {
   -- one field for each typeclass method
    protoName :: String
}

instance Nameable ProtoNameable where
    name = protoName

toProto :: SomeNameable -> ProtoNameable
toProto (SomeNameable x) = ProtoNameable { protoName = name x }

fromProto :: ProtoNameable -> SomeNameable
fromProto = SomeNameable
```

As we can see, this fancy existential type `SomeNameable` has the same structure and information as `ProtoNameable`, which is isomorphic to `String`, so when you are using this lofty concept `SomeNameable`, you're really just saying `String` in a convoluted way. So why not just say `String`?

Your `items` definition has exactly the same information as this definition:

```
items = [ "Don", "Empire State" ]
```

I should add a few notes about this "protoization": it is only as straightforward as this when the typeclass you are existentially quantifying over has a certain structure: namely when it looks like an OO class.

```
class Foo a where
    method1 :: ... -> a -> ...
    method2 :: ... -> a -> ...
    ...
```

That is, each method only uses `a` once as an argument.  If you have something like `Num`

```
class Num a where
    (+) :: a -> a -> a
    ...
```

which uses `a` in multiple argument positions, or as a result, then eliminating the existential is not as easy, [but still possible](http://okmij.org/ftp/Computation/Existentials.html).  However my recommendation to do this changes from a frustration to a subtle context-dependent choice, because of the complexity and distant relationship of the two representations.  However, *every time* I have seen existentials used in practice it is with the `Foo` kind of tyepclass, where it only adds needless complexity, so I quite emphatically [consider it an antipattern](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/).  In most of these cases I recommend eliminating the entire class from your codebase and exclusively using the protoized type (after you give it a good name).

Also, if you *do* need to downcast, then existentials aren't your man.  You can either use an algebraic data type, as others people have answered, or you can use [Data.Dynamic](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Data-Dynamic.html) (which is basically an existential over [Typeable](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Typeable.html).  But don't do that; a Haskell programmer resorting to `Dynamic` is ungentlemanlike.  An ADT is the way to go, where you characterize all the possible types it could be in one place (which is necessary so that the functions that do the "downcasting" know that they handle all possible cases).

Answer (score 6):

I like @hammar's answer, and you should also check out [this article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types#Example%3a_heterogeneous_lists) which provides another example.

But, you might want to think differently about your types. The boxing of `Nameable` into the `SomeNameable` data type usually makes me start thinking about whether a union type for the specific case is meaningful.

```
data Entity = H Human | B Building
instance Nameable Entity where ...

items = [H (Human "Don"), B (Building "Town Hall")]
```

Comment: You could could just use `items = ["Don", "Town Hall"]`, since it contains exactly the same information.

Comment: @luqui This allows you to pattern match on the `Entity` constructor, so it does carry more information than just a String.  `Human` and `Building` are probably unnecessary though.

Comment: Oh whoops.  I cursorily saw the signs of an existential and didn't read in detail.

Comment: My actual case is at https://github.com/xaviershay/xtdo-hs/blob/master/Xtdo.hs, where I have `Task` and `RecurringTaskDefinition`. They need to be treated the same for finding/deleting, but they are different "things".

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why you want to use the same function for
getting the name of a `Human` and the name of a `Building`.

If their names are used in fundamentally different ways,
except maybe for simple things like printing them,
then you probably want two
different functions for that. The type system
will automatically guide you to choose the right function
to use in each situation.

But if having a name is something significant about the
whole purpose of your program, and a `Human` and a `Building`
are really pretty much the same thing in that respect as far as your program
is concerned, then you would define their type together:

```
data NameableThing =
  Human { name :: String } |
  Building { name :: String }
```

That gives you a polymorphic function `name` that works for
whatever particular flavor of `NameableThing` you happen to have,
without needing to get into type classes.

Usually you would use a type class for a different kind of situation:
if you have some kind of non-trivial operation that has the same purpose
but a different implementation for several different types.
Even then, it's often better to use some other approach instead, like
passing a function as a parameter (a "higher order function", or "HOF").

Haskell type classes are a beautiful and powerful tool, but they are totally
different than what is called a "class" in object-oriented languages,
and they are used far less often.

And I certainly don't recommend complicating your program by using an advanced
extension to Haskell like Existential Qualification just to fit into
an object-oriented design pattern.

Comment: Sorry, my example is contrived. If you're curious, here's my full program: https://github.com/xaviershay/xtdo-hs/blob/master/Xtdo.hs I need to be able to treat `Task` and `RecurringTaskDefinition` in similar ways, note that `deleteTaskByName` and `deleteRecurringByName` are pretty much the same function.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use Existentially Quanitified types and do it like this:

```
data T = forall a. Nameable a => MkT a
items = [MkT (Human "bla"), MkT (Building "bla")]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a look at [the code](https://github.com/xaviershay/xtdo-hs/blob/master/Xtdo.hs) that this question is abstracting from. For this, I would recommend merging the `Task` and `RecurringTaskDefinition` types:

```
data Task
    = Once
        { name :: String
        , scheduled :: Maybe Day
        , category :: TaskCategory
        }
    | Recurring
        { name :: String
        , nextOccurrence :: Day
        , frequency :: RecurFrequency
        }
type ProgramData = [Task] -- don't even need a new data type for this any more
```

Then, the `name` function works just fine on either type, and the functions you were complaining about like `deleteTask` and `deleteRecurring` don't even need to exist -- you can just use the standard `delete` function as usual.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. For the time being I've gotten away with using a higher-order function, but I think I'll try your way too to see how it falls out. Thanks.